# Java type inference of generic exception type

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to have a functor F which may throw multiple exceptions (in the example below Checked and SQLException). I want to be able to call a function with F as an argument, such that whatever checked exceptions F throws (except SQLException which would be handled internally) get rethrown.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class Checked extends Exception {
    public Checked() {
        super();
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<T, U, E extends Exception> {
    U apply(T t) throws E, SQLException;
}

class ConnectionPool {
    public static <T, E extends Exception> T call(Class<E> exceptionClass, SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<Connection, T, E> f) throws E {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unimportant");
    }
}

class Test {
    static Void mayThrow0(Connection c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unimportant");
    }        
    static <E extends Exception> Void mayThrow1(Connection c) throws E {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unimportant");
    }
    static <E1 extends Exception, E2 extends Exception> Void mayThrow2(Connection c) throws E1, E2 {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unimportant");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Intended code, but doesn't compile
        ConnectionPool.call(RuntimeException.class, Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1);
        ConnectionPool.call(Checked.class, Test::<Checked, SQLException>mayThrow2);

        // Type inference works if the function doesn't actually throw SQLException (doesn't help me)
        ConnectionPool.call(RuntimeException.class, Test::mayThrow0);
        ConnectionPool.call(Checked.class, Test::<Checked>mayThrow1);

        // Can workaround by manually specifying the type parameters to ConnectionPool.call (but is tedious)
        ConnectionPool.<Void, RuntimeException>call(RuntimeException.class, Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1);
        ConnectionPool.<Void, Checked>call(Checked.class, Test::<Checked, SQLException>mayThrow2);
    }
}
```

Intuitively, I would expect the above example to compile but it doesn't. Is there a way to get this to work, or is the workaround of specifying the type arguments the only way? The compile error is:

```
Test.java:34: error: incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
        ConnectionPool.call(RuntimeException.class, Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1); // doesn't compile
                           ^
    equality constraints: RuntimeException
    lower bounds: SQLException
  where E,T are type-variables:
    E extends Exception declared in method <T,E>call(Class<E>,SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<Connection,T,E>)
    T extends Object declared in method <T,E>call(Class<E>,SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<Connection,T,E>)
Test.java:35: error: incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
        ConnectionPool.call(Checked.class, Test::<Checked, SQLException>mayThrow2); // doesn't compile
                           ^
    equality constraints: Checked
    lower bounds: SQLException,Checked
  where E,T are type-variables:
    E extends Exception declared in method <T,E>call(Class<E>,SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<Connection,T,E>)
    T extends Object declared in method <T,E>call(Class<E>,SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<Connection,T,E>)
2 errors
```

Comment: Your code compiles for me in Eclipse, even the following compiled: 
    ConnectionPool.call(RuntimeException.class, Test1::mayThrow1);
    ConnectionPool.call(Checked.class, Test1::mayThrow2); with no type hints. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Pedro javac 1.8.0_152 (Oracle JDK)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a strange peculiarity of the Java parser (in jdk 1.8u152 and 9.0.1, but *not* the compiler built into Eclipse) so when you have

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<T, U, E extends Exception> {
    U apply(T t) throws E, SQLException;
}
```

and you pass `Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1` it binds E to SQLException when it creates an instance of the interface.

You can make it *not* do that by simply swapping the declared exceptions in the interface, i.e. just do

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<T, U, E extends Exception> {
    U apply(T t) throws SQLException, E;
}
```

and then it compiles!

The relevant part of the JLS is [section 18.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2.5). But I can't see where it explains the above behaviour.

Comment: The JLS [section on Resolution (18.4)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.4) might help explain this behavior too.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my comment, it didn't actually compile, but it somehow ran on Eclipse. I think the compilation error is actually expected. The signature of the call method is:

```java
public static <T, E extends Exception> T call(Class<E> exceptionClass, SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<Connection, T, E> f) throws E
```

and you are using it as:

```java
ConnectionPool.call(RuntimeException.class, Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1);
```

By the signature of the method, the class of the first parameter(RuntimeException) must match the generic of mayThrow1(SQLException), since they are both E in the signature.

Comment: Strange. I get the same thing. Eclipse compiles and runs the code just fine. But if I try to compile manually by calling javac or using gradle, I get a compilation error.

Comment: same here linux 1.8.0.152 compiles run fine on eclipse

Answer (score 0):

When you see `public static <T, E extends Exception> T call(Class<E> exceptionClass, SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<Connection, T, E> f) throws E` that tells :

- type of `E` in `Class<E>` (your first argument, exceptionClass) and
- type of `E` in `SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<Connection, T, E> f) throws E`

shall be of same type/subtype.

Hence the `E` ( i.e `SQLException`) in `SQLExceptionThrowingFunction` is expected to be of subtype of `E` (*exceptionClass*), which is passed as `RuntimeException`).  (this happens when you call `ConnectionPool.call(RuntimeException.class, Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1);`

Since this expectation fails, you get compilation error.

You can validate this by changing...

- `ConnectionPool.call(RuntimeException.class, Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1);` to
- `ConnectionPool.call(`**Exception**`.class, fitest.Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1);` which will remove the error on that line.

Not sure if that is what your intention is initially.

1:
 What you can do to use generic stuff (if you don't care about declaring exceptions is change call method as below and then all your code will work.

```
public static <T> T call2(Class exceptionClass, SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<Connection,T, Exception> f)
{
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unimportant");
}
```

2: Or you can just call like without defining the type. e.g

```
ConnectionPool.call(RuntimeException.class, Test::mayThrow0);
ConnectionPool.call(Checked.class, Test::mayThrow1);
```

I am not sure if that solves your question. If you have different intention, when you said `Is there a way to get this to work, or is the workaround of specifying the type arguments the only way` what actually you wanted` then please share the pseduo syntax how would you like stuff to work.

Comment: This. `E` cannot stand for `RuntimeException` and `SQLException` at the same time. Without the type hints it works fine (but will not throw `RuntimeException` nor `Checked`, as these types are different from `E`).

Comment: Exactly @PetrJaneček and that was what I meant in explanation from part1. And telling OP to use "`Exception`" as `Exception` and `SQLException` are same `E`.

Comment: Also I cannot read properly, now I finally see what he's trying to achieve. Yeah, that's probably not possible without explicit generic "hints" (that are wrong, but will work because of erasure). The safest bet for him is to simply declare `throws Exception` or `throws MyWrapperException` that he'll wrap around whatever the inner function throws (except SQL exception, obviously).

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion "Hence the E ( i.e SQLException) in SQLExceptionThrowingFunction " - where does it say that E is an SQLException? E is just a generic parameter in the definition of interface SQLExceptionThrowingFunction.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException This is where he is "calling" the call function i.e here  `ConnectionPool.call(RuntimeException.class, Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1)`

Comment: @Optional where is the connection? He is passing the value `Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1` to the method `call`. That is a method reference which gets converted into an instance of an implicit class that extends `interface SQLExceptionThrowingFunction<T, U, E extends Exception>`. But what I'm asking is, just because you've mentioned `SQLException` as a generic parameter for the `mayThrow1` method, why does that mean that any one of the generic parameters of `interface SQLExceptionThrowingFunction` should also be `SQLException`? Why E in particular and not T or U?

Comment: Sir, @DodgyCodeException I think, you have missed the signature of `mayThrow1` which returns a subtype of `Exception`. (For same reason you can't do `Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1`). Now by doing type cast `SQLException` we are explicitly telling that the `FunctionalInterface` will throw an Exception of this type. Which will take a `Connection` when called with `apply` in call2 (currently obfuscated). Also why not T or U, because it's not T and U, that is part of apply definition.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm still not sure I understand completely. The method reference `Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1` means that the method `SQLExceptionThrowingFunction.apply()` must throw `SQLException`. But it is already specified as throwing `SQLException` (in addition to E). If it was specified to throw just E, then I would accept that E must be whatever `mayThrow1` throws. But E can be anything you like, because `apply` is already specified to throw SQLException so E doesn't also have to be SQLException.

Comment: You are correct when you say `The method reference Test::<SQLException>mayThrow1 means that the method SQLExceptionThrowingFunction.apply()`.That is not the issue. OP is not directly calling "apply" in main method. Had it been case, it was fine. He is calling via a wrapper method call, which in Addition also puts a restriction that the Exception that `SQLExceptionThrowingFunction` will throw, is also of type/subtype that is passed in 1st argument/parameter of call method. `Class<E>`. Right? This is because both the argument of call uses same `E`. Hence the compilation error @DodgyCodeException

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158407/discussion-between-dodgycodeexception-and-optional).

Comment: @Optional Changing `RuntimeException` to `Exception` still gives a compile error for the next line for me.

Comment: @River That was an example. Offcourse you have to adapt next line as well, to solve next line problem. The reason for failure in next line is same as SQLException does not fall hierarchy of "Checked" class. So in this case on such workaround could be to make (Additionally) Checked extend SQLException.

Comment: @Optional ah, I made an edit to make that more clear.